# send email to current user email in flutter using msal_js

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a flutter web app that is a inventory surplus app. log in using msal_js and that works but I need the app to send a email to the current logged in user what's in the datatable of this code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surplus/form.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart' show kIsWeb;
import 'dart:html' as html; // This import is specific to Flutter web

class SummaryPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<FormData> formData;
  final String school;

  const SummaryPage({super.key, required this.formData, required this.school});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Summary'),
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            DataTable(
              columns: const [
                DataColumn(label: Text('School')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('CPS Number')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Item Description')),
                DataColumn(label: Text('Reason For Surplus')),
              ],
              rows: formData
                  .map((e) => DataRow(cells: [
                        DataCell(Text(school)),
                        DataCell(Text(e.cpsNumber)),
                        DataCell(Text(e.itemDescription)),
                        DataCell(Text(e.selectedReason ?? "")),
                      ]))
                  .toList(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 24.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  // Assuming you have the user's email address
                  final userEmail = 'current users email '; // Placeholder for the user's email
                  final subject = Uri.encodeComponent('Summary Information');
                  final body = Uri.encodeComponent(buildEmailBody());
                  // Trigger the mail client
                  if (kIsWeb) {
                    html.window.open('mailto:$userEmail?subject=$subject&body=$body', '_blank');
                  } else {
                    // Handle non-web platform if necessary
                  }

                  Navigator.of(context).popUntil((route) => route.isFirst);
                },
                child: Text('Submit'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }

  String buildEmailBody() {
    final buffer = StringBuffer()
      ..writeln('Summary for $school')
      ..writeln('')
      ..writeln('CPS Number | Item Description | Reason For Surplus')
      ..writeln('--------------------------------');

    for (final item in formData) {
      buffer.writeln('${item.cpsNumber} | ${item.itemDescription} | ${item.selectedReason}');
    }

    return buffer.toString();
  }
}
```

I am still really new to flutter development! so any help on this would be amazing!!!
please let me know if you need anything else! and thank you in advance for the help!!!

Comment: This should really be two separate questions: 1) How to get users email after logging in using msal_js (answer: make a query to the graph api https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/issues/756#issuecomment-857759903). 2) How to send email from flutter app (answer: you can't send directly from clientside app, you will need some serverside component).